# Cakephp add-on for account administration

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a cakephp add-on component that handles account administration tasks such as confirming an email address, resetting a forgotten password, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [CakeDC User Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/users) (from the [CakeDC Github page](http://cakedc.github.com/))